# Proper way to update a Reference in Rugged

Tags: git, libgit2, rugged

As a followup to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072920/performing-a-fast-forward-merge-with-rugged), I'm trying to update one reference (e.g. `release`) to point to another reference (e.g. `master`).

---

If I have a `master` and a `release` branch, and `master` is a single commit ahead of `release`, I'd like to "fast-forward" `release` to `master`.  I try this:

```
r = Rugged::Repository.new(".") # assume we're on the `release` branch
r.references.update(r.head.resolve, r.branches['master'].target_id)
```

This almost works, but leaves my repo in a state like this:

```
On branch release
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/release' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
 Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   file
```

Am I missing a step?  I'm expecting my staging area to be "clean".

I've tried `r.index.write_tree(r)` and `r.index.write`, but no dice.

Comment: Is that the totality of you're code?  You seem to not be checking out the target, so the index contains the previous data.  I don't understand why, since you seem to do the checkout step in the question you linked to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing a "fast-forward" merge with Rugged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072920/performing-a-fast-forward-merge-with-rugged)

Comment: I don't follow -- I already stated I'm assuming the release branch is already checked out when the Repository is instantiated.

Comment: This is a tricky terminology.  It's not checked out, you're "on the release branch", but the contents from master aren't there yet.  libgit2's checkout functionality will update the working directory and the index with the new contents.  If you don't do that, status will show that you have changes.

Comment: So...what do I need to do?  I tried `r.head = 'refs/heads/release'`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Hmm...calling `r.reset(r.head.target, :hard)` as mentioned in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971814/rugged-merge-commit-from-origin-does-not-update-working-tree?rq=1#comment44340761_27971814) seems to do what I want.  Is that the wrong approach?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to your other question?

Comment: It leaves a dirty index, as I pointed out in this question.

Comment: Your code - in this question - does not show you doing a checkout.  Can you post the actual code that you're using?

Comment: Just prefix the first line with "git checkout release" on the command line.

Comment: Okay.  So use the code in the answer to your other question which calls *Rugged checkout*, that will update the index and workdir.

Comment: No change; `r.checkout_tree(r.branches["release"].target)` does nothing.